# Kafka partition blocked when infra problem in a single instance of application

Tags: java, kubernetes, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a problem with some micro service when running the microservice with kubernetes with many PODs.
I use the Manual commit strategy so I should acknowledge or not every message.
All the instance of the application belong the same kafka group. And the topic have at least 20 partition divided between the PODs. When consuming the message the listener make a call to a extern component (like a rest API by WebClient or RestTemplate, or a kafka producer of a different topic) . The Kafka consumer look like this:

```
  @KafkaListener(topics = "topic")
  @Trace
  public void listen(@Payload Object message, , Acknowledgment acknowledgment)) {
  try {
    api.call(message);
    acknowledgment.acknowledge();
  } catch (InfraException e) {
    acknowledgment.nack(1000);
  }
```

But sometime this external component have infra problems and is not available. The problem usually happens when for some reason a single POD have connectivity issues. As the message is not acknowledge, he continue to be consumed, what is good. But the problem is that the message continue to be send to the same problematic instance of the application and is never redirected to another 'healthy' consumer.. As the consumer is able to get message from kafka and send heartbeats it is never considered a problematic consumer for kafka even after the rebalancing.
There some strategy or something we can do in the config to solve this problem or avoid the partition to be blocked?

Thank you for your attention so far.

Comment: If you make Actuator return a error http code on your "not available" condition, and have k8s terminate the pod via a healthcheck probe, then the group would rebalance to all healthy pods. Also, I suggest making the api call have a backoff/retry loop

Comment: Kafka assigns whole topic partitions to individual consumers; individual messages aren't routed beyond that.  If a consumer has a problem processing some message, unless something happens to cause Kafka to reassign the partition (as @OneCricketeer suggests, terminating the pod will do) the same consumer will keep receiving messages for that partition.